# jQuery UI datepicker with multiple altField and altFormat

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I am trying to define a date input field with two alt date display fields where they all have distinct date formats. In the example below, if my date input is 013017 then I want my alt date display fields to show

> Display 1: 2017-01-30
>
> Display 2: 01-30-17

But instead I'm getting

> Display 1: 2017-01-30, 01-30-17
>
> Display 2: 2017-01-30, 01-30-17

Here is my markup:

```
<p>Date Input: <input type="text" id="datepicker1"> </p>
<p>Display 1: <input type="text" id="alternate1" size="30"> </p>
<p>Display 2: <input type="text" id="alternate2" size="30"> </p>
```

Here is my js:

```
$( function() {    
    $( "#datepicker1" ).datepicker({
        dateFormat: "mmddy",
        altField:   "#alternate1, #alternate2",
        altFormat:  "yy-mm-dd, mm-dd-y"
    });    
});
```

here is a jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/5rqtj056/

Comment: `altFormat` takes a format string and formats the selected date. `altField` takes a jQuery selector, so using multiple controls is possible. If you want to format the second control, you'll need to do it outside of the datepicker options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `altFormat` property accepts one format date, to be used for representing elements retrieved by the altField selector. 
This a snippet from jQuery UI official documentation

```
altFormat 

Type: String
Default: ""
The dateFormat to be used for the altField option. This allows one date format to be shown to the user for selection purposes, while a different format is actually sent behind the scenes. For a full list of the possible formats see the formatDate function
```

In order to do that, you need to bind an event on the #alternate1 for example and filling that one, you will convert the date and then fill the #alternate2

Here your new JS code:

```
$( function() {

  $( "#datepicker1" ).datepicker({
    dateFormat: "mmddy",
    altField: "#alternate1",
    altFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
    onSelect: function(dateText) {
      $('#alternate1').trigger("change");
    }
  });  

  $("#alternate1").change(elaborateDate);
  $("#datepicker1").keyup(elaborateDate);

  function elaborateDate() {
    var alt1Date = $('#alternate1').val();
    var newDate = $.datepicker.formatDate( "mm-dd-y", new Date(alt1Date) );
    $('#alternate2').val(alt1Date);
  }

});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/5rqtj056/8/

Comment: Looks like this only works if I select a date using the calendar UI. It doesn't work if I type in 013017.

Comment: Yep sure, because the event is bind only to the calendar, give me a min to update it in order to work also typing

Comment: done, updated both the answer and the example in jsfiddle